# error in SMOTE function for categorical data

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes

I have a categorical data with target variable as factor.

`mydata <- data.frame(x = c(rep("good", 3), rep("bad", 3)), target =  c(rep("yes",5), "no"))`

```
> mydata
     x target
1 good    yes
2 good    yes
3 good    yes
4  bad    yes
5  bad    yes
6  bad     no
```

So one can say that we have imbalanced target variable here. I now try to use `SMOTE` function from `DMwR` package.

`SMOTE( target ~ . , mydata)`

But I get the following errors.

```
Error in factor(newCases[, a], levels = 1:nlevels(data[, a]), labels = levels(data[,  : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 0 should be 1 or 2
In addition: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

What is happening here ?